# How to change cookie life time in IBM Websphere portal?

Tags: cookies, websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

I add to my RenderResponse cookie, and set maxAge = 1 hour.
But, it is expired when I end session. Of course if I have session more than 1 hour - cookie expired in 1 hour. But if I end session less than 1 hour and start again - cookie expired.
How can I set cookie what do not depend of session?
I use IBM Websphere portal 8. I set cookie in filter (extend RenderFilter):

    `private void setCookie(RenderResponse response){
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(COOKIE_NAME, "true");
        Integer coockieTime = 60*60;
        cookie.setMaxAge(coockieTime);
        response.addProperty(cookie);
    }`

Comment: sorry, but do you mean by end session closing the browser or only logging out?

Comment: Both. Closing browser and logout clears cookies.

Comment: closing the browser is expected as you have so called session cookies.
Session in this case does not mean HTTPSession it means Browser session. About the logout I would to try it on my own